# IONIC: Passing data from one directive to another

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic2

I am using a drop down ionic-option to display all children from my database. I want the *Baby's id* from the object, **babydata** to be passed on to the **ChildData** object's *Baby's id** to be used in a seperate form. Here is the Code :

```
    <ion-item> 
  <ion-label>Child</ion-label>
  <!-- <ion-icon name="happy" item-left></ion-icon> -->
  <ion-select  okText="Select" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="ChildData.BabyProfile_idBabyProfile">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of babydata" ng-value="item.idBabyProfile" >
      <p [innerHTML]="item.firstName"></p>
      <p [innerHTML]="item.lastName"></p>
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

However, when the form data is submitted, it gives me the following results as shown in the payload[  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDPvY.png ]

Instead of giving me the ID, it gives me the firstname and lastname. How can I solve this so that I pass the the baby id from babydata  to ChildData. ??

Answer (score 0):

It should be "value" not "ng-value"

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let item of babydata" value="item.idBabyProfile" >
      <p [innerHTML]="item.firstName"></p>
      <p [innerHTML]="item.lastName"></p>
    </ion-option>
</ion-option>
```

Since he can't find the value attribute it defaults to the option content (in your case, the html containing the firstName and lastName).